# Is it possible to transition from an inset box-shadow to a regualr box-shadow?

Tags: css, sass, transition

This might not make sense out of context, but I'm working on something where I would like there to be an inset box-shadow which transitions to a normal box-shadow. The transition works without the inset, but breaks with. Possible or not?

```
.foo{
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 0px 4px grey,
    inset -4px 0px 4px grey;
  background: cornsilk;
  &:hover{
     box-shadow: 1px 9px 4px 9px grey;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/bobam/pen/ZEWBeJp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct transition for the box-shadow inset to regular is not possible. But, there is one hack that can give a closer effect.

Consider the following css:

```css
.foo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #aaa;
    animation: boxShadowOut 1s;
}
.foo:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa;
    animation: boxShadowIn 1s;
}
    
@keyframes boxShadowIn {
    0% { box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #aaa; }
    50% { box-shadow: none; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa; }
}
    
@keyframes boxShadowOut {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa; }
    50% { box-shadow: none; }
    100% { box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #aaa; }
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I suspected animation may hold the key.

Comment: Yes. It will hold the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with transition. You simply need to define all the shadows at once and play with the values to make them `0` when you don't need the shadow:

```css
.foo {
  height: 8rem;
  width: 8rem;
  margin:10px;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 4px 0px 4px grey, 
    inset -4px 0px 4px grey,
    0px 0px 0px 0px grey;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
  background: cornsilk;
}
.foo:hover {
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0px 0px 0px grey, 
    inset 0px 0px 0px grey,
    1px 9px 4px 9px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
</div>
```